# Laravel - How to validate dates with relative formats?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-validation

PHP defines the [relative formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) and Laravel doesn't seen to have an [available validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#available-validation-rules) for that. For example:

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'created-at-from' => 'relative_format',
        'created-at-until' => 'nullable|relative_format|gte:created-at-from'
    ];
}
```

How can we validate those formats?

**UPDATE**

What I'm using now:

Create a rule class.

```
php artisan make:rule RelativeFormat
```

Put the logic.

```
/**
 * Determine if the validation rule passes.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return bool
 */
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return (bool) strtotime($value);
}
```

And validates:

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'created-at-from' => [new RelativeFormat],
        'created-at-until' => ['nullable', new RelativeFormat]
    ];
}
```

Comment: The 'date' rule should work with any format understood by the parser.  Did you try it?

Comment: @Devon yes, I tried "10 days", "1 hour" and the validator fails...

Comment: ok, that's too bad.  Never tried it, but based on the docs, you'd think it would work.  You'll have to write your own validation rule,  Laravel makes it pretty easy.

Comment: Even if you do get the relative formats to work, `gte:created-at-from` will not work because it will do a string comparison, you need custom rules or to rethink what kind of dates you're allowing your users to input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create your own validation rule:

```
Validator::extend('relative_format', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return (bool) strtotime($value);
});
```

And add it to your AppServiceProvider.